# Issue in compiling project after updating to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Recently upgraded my project to Xcode 8 and having trouble compiling my project. Everything was working well in Xcode 7 but can't seem to figure out what's wrong here.

Keep getting Nullability specifier 'nullable' conflicts with existing specifier 'no null'.

Here's code:

```
@interface NotificationViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webNotification;

@end

@implementation NotificationViewController

// Error on next line
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(nullable     NSError *)error
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Any insight?

Comment: Please only post relevant code.

Comment: }

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(nullable NSError *)error
{

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation for the `didFailLoadWithError:` delegate method. Note how it is different than what you have in your code. You need to make it the same.

Simply drop the mis-use of `nullable`.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
```